# Magento : Catalog URL Rewrites Index Process is Working Now

Tags: magento-1.9, indexing

I am running magento 1.9 CE. when I am trying to index it shows this error -         **Catalog URL Rewrites Index process is working now. Please try run this process later.** [image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Clear all files inside of var/locks/ directory
2. Apply 777 permission to var/locks/
3. Recreate index executing shell commands:

php magentodirectory/shell/indexer.php -reindex catalog_url

Comment: Unable to find locks folder in Var

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to empty the table call core_url_rewrites from you database and again do this process.
But first please take backup of this table and then empty it.

Thanks

Comment: This is incorrect, you don't need to clear this table. You can delete the files from var/locks/ to make the index working again.

Comment: Unable to find locks folder in Var

Comment: If not found lock folder then you can go with my solution @alokkumar

Comment: i have empty the table call core_url_rewrites from my database but still its not working